# what is the command-line options for selecting the server port for expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using this guy https://github.com/twilson63/express-coffee

To start the server, the docs say to issue this command:
`cake dev`

is there a way to select the port number via the command line? Similar to `rails s --port 3010`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put "PORT=XXXX" before "cake dev" :)

```
PORT=2000 cake dev
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ NODE_PORT=3000 node ./app.js
```

inside app.js

```
var port = process.env.NODE_PORT;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `Cakefile` it doesn't look like that's an option, but it should be easy to fix. Have a look at the Cakefile in [frappe](https://github.com/dweldon/frappe) (a similar project).